# Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test, Line 21 Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
@tour int,
@tourname varchar(50) OUTPUT,  
@tourdepartures varchar(50) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
SET @tourname = (select [tour name] from dbo.products1 where tour = @tour)

SET @tourdepartures = (select ddate7 from dbo.TDEPART1 where tour = @tour and depart > convert(int,getdate()))

END
```

I want to use a stored procedure to populate a label on my asp.net page
and a dropdownlist

@tourname will be populated into a single label

while @tourdepartures will be multiple dates, that i want in a dropdownlist

however when i run my sp i get this error

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test, Line 21
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
```

and it works when i do

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
@tour int,
@tourname varchar(50) OUTPUT,  
@tourdepartures varchar(50) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
SET @tourname = (select [tour name] from dbo.product where tour = @tour)

SET @tourdepartures = (select top 1 ddate7 from abcfilestest.dbo.TDEPART where tour = @tour and depart > convert(int,getdate()))

END
```

but it only gives me the first departure date

Comment: Is the column name correct? "tour name" or "tourname"?

Comment: Yeah I think it has to do with the fact I'm returning more departure dates than tour names but why cant I set my @tourdepartures to more than one date

Comment: because your assigning it to a single variable. If you want to return all of the dates, get rid of the assignment and just read the list on the client. If you want a comma-delimited list or something, your code is going to get more involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the second `SET` and just return a resultset that you can use a reader with:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
@tour int,
@tourname varchar(50) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
SET @tourname = (select [tour name] from dbo.products where tour = @tour)

select ddate7 from abcfilestest.dbo.TDEPART where tour = @tour and depart > convert(int,getdate())

END
```

Comment: thanks i kept trying to put it in a variable so i could populate them into listbox and labels easily

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to remove the error, but I don't think it's really what you want:

```
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
SET @tourname = (select TOP 1 [tour name] from dbo.products where tour = @tour)

SET @tourdepartures = (select TOP 1 ddate7 from abcfilestest.dbo.TDEPART where tour = @tour and depart > convert(int,getdate()))
```

If you really want a list of all of the tour dates, change the last statement to

```
select ddate7 from abcfilestest.dbo.TDEPART where tour = @tour and depart > convert(int,getdate())
```

and parse the result set on the client as you usually would.

Also, for the love of all that's holy, rename that `ddate7` column to something meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

A scalar variable can only hold one value. The query you are using returns more than one value. YOu have several choices and the right one depends on your situation.

If you only want the latest date, use top 1 and order by date desc in your select.

If you want all the dates, then use a table variable not a scalar variable. I know I can use table variable in SQL Server 2008 as stored procedure parameter, not sure about 2005. You could just return 2 recordsets (so that you are consistent in what you are returning) or one output variable and one select instead of using output variables.